# What changes does Apple require for app submissions as of 1st of May?

Tags: ios, app-store, submit, rule

I've heard about and read some of the new regulations from Apple about submitting apps to app store.

Firstly, the new version of my app is nearly done and it supports the 4-inch screen now.

About the UDID regulation, I don't exactly know what it means and am not quite sure whether my app follows the rule, how should I check this?

And before I submit my app, what steps and setting should I do in my project? My last submitting was over 1 year ago with other's help, so I'm not confident in myself.

For example, how many icons do I need in my project? (currently I have icon.png, icon@2x.png, icon-small.png, appIcon-small@2x.png, icon-72.png, and icon-small-50.png).

I just want to be fully prepared to submit my app.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: "Also If you have not already done so, stop using the unique device identifier (UDID) provided by the uniqueIdentifier property of the UIDevice class. That property was deprecated in iOS 5.0, and starting May 1, 2013 the App Store will no longer accept new apps or app updates that use that identifier. Instead, apps should use the identifierForVendor property of the UIDevice class or the advertisingIdentifier property of the ASIdentifierManager class, as appropriate" - see "iOS App Programming Guide" for all details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Icon sizes are listed here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html

The biggest shock for me, when submitting an app after a hiatus, was the 1024x1024 App Store icon. Who has artwork that big???

You will also need double-resolution screen shots for all device sizes (iPhone 4, iPhone 5, and iPad).

My book has a pretty good checklist of the things you'll need as part of your final preparations before submission:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch09.html#_final_app_preparations

Comment: Thanks! This would help. BTW, I think the 1024*1024 icon is probably for retina screens of macbook pro.